# Custom "contact user" templates

Tags: support, feature-request, moderation

Is it possible to customize the "contact user" templates?

I like the idea that the contact with users are handled in a similar way across moderators, but the wording in the templates as they come OOB could use some improvement.

So is it possible to customize for example the sockpuppet template and make it more usable for our community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the standpoint of "Is it currently possible", the answer is **no**, you cannot customize templates that are stored on the site itself. The templates are immutable.

For now, I would recommend forging up your own personal template and stashing it somewhere you can easily access. It could be a text file on your computer, or it could be somewhere online if you find yourself on multiple machines frequently. Either way, it's meant that you can quickly flick to it, copy the relevant template you pre-forged, and paste it into the moderator message. It is hackish, but may as well have it some way available, neh? ♪

Comment: i dont like [haggis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haggis) :S